# sre_constants.error: invalid group reference Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have written a python regex.

```
import re
nt = re.sub('NT:\s*[^,)]*',r'\1', message)
```

message contains the data.
 (NT: 167 ms, ST: 2509 ms, XT: 1325 ms)

If I run the regular expression on the data with the purpose of extracting `167 ms` I get the following error.

```
File "test.py", line 79, in <module>
    nt = re.sub('NT:\s*[^,)]*',r'\1', message)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 275, in filter
    return sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 802, in expand_template
    raise error, "invalid group reference"
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `\1` refers the first group index, since your reex won't contain any capturing groups, it displays the above error message.

Comment: You might want to match using `re.findall` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group`

```
import re
nt = re.sub('\(NT:\s*([^,)]*),.*$',r'\1', message)

                     ^^    ^^
```

Try this.You didn't have a `capturing group` still you were `referencing` it by `\1`.That is why the error.Put the one you want in a `group ()` and then `backreference it`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/21#python

You will have to match the whole string and then replace if you want `nt` to be `167 ms`.Else you can use

```
nt=re.findall(r"NT:\s*([^,)]*)",string)[0]
```

Comment: your findall query is working for NT and ST but now for XT ? I can't figure out why that is?